# Current IP address as visible from the internet?

Tags: command-line, networking, ip

I know I can get the locally assigned IP address of my current machine by the local router like so:

```
ifconfig
```

However, I want to know what my IP address is as visible from the outside world. Or, in other words, the IP address of the upper-most router within my private network. Normally I could just [ask Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=my%20ip) "my ip", but I want this to be scriptable.

Is there a way to figure out this address from CLI without just scraping the results of the above Google search?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/how-can-i-get-my-external-ip-address-in-bash

Comment: `netcat` worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

You can use :

```
curl ifconfig.me
```