# How to display the IP address of the default Interface with Internet connection?

Tags: networking, scripting, ip, ifconfig

I need to create a script that outputs the internal IP address, that is configured as the default Interface.

Comment: Do you mean the one used for sending to the default gateway?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get my external IP address in bash?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/how-can-i-get-my-external-ip-address-in-bash)

Comment: @jasonwryan not a dupe (or not a dupe of that one anyway), the OP wants the internal IP, not the external.

Comment: Hauke, this might be it, if the interpretation of the "default" value from the route command is that that is.

Comment: yeah, Jason that has dependencies to external libraries. I was looking for the output without dependencies.

Comment: @MarcellodeSales no, it has no dependencies. It is just looking for something different. You are showing how to get the IP of a machine in the internal network while the dupe is about getting the external IP. Two very different things. Jason was confused because your original question was asking for a "public" IP which is not what your answer returns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's another slightly terser method using `procfs` (assumes you're using Linux):

```
default_iface=$(awk '$2 == 00000000 { print $1 }' /proc/net/route)
ip addr show dev "$default_iface" | awk '$1 ~ /^inet/ { sub("/.*", "", $2); print $2 }'
```

This returns both the IPv4 and (if available) the IPv6 address of the interface. You can change the test if you only want one or the other (look for `inet` for IPv4, and `inet6` for IPv6).

---

```
$ default_iface=$(awk '$2 == 00000000 { print $1 }' /proc/net/route)
$ ip addr show dev "$default_iface" | awk '$1 ~ /^inet/ { sub("/.*", "", $2); print $2 }'
10.0.2.15
fe80::a00:27ff:fe45:b085
```

```
$ ip addr show dev "$default_iface" | awk '$1 == "inet" { sub("/.*", "", $2); print $2 }'
10.0.2.15
```

```
$ ip addr show dev "$default_iface" | awk '$1 == "inet6" { sub("/.*", "", $2); print $2 }'
fe80::a00:27ff:fe45:b085
```

Answer (score 12):

Lots of good answers here, but wanted to throw in my usual approach:

The simplest solution is to get the route for a public internet address:

```
$ ip route get 1.1.1.1 | grep -oP 'src \K\S+'
192.168.0.20
```

Another solution is to get the default gateway, and then get the IP addr used to communicate with that gateway:

```
$ ip route get $(ip route show 0.0.0.0/0 | grep -oP 'via \K\S+') | grep -oP 'src \K\S+'
192.168.0.20
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I wrote:

1. Get the default interface from the "route" command.

It will print out which interface is the "default". For my host, I need to get the last column of the default line.

```
[root@pppdc9prd3ga mdesales]# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.4.0     *               255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 bridge0
10.132.60.0     *               255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth4
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth4
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 bridge0
default         10.132.60.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth4
```

2. Use "ifconfig" to retrieve the IP address of that interface.

Just getting the addr: value.

```
[root@pppdc9prd3ga mdesales]# ifconfig eth4
eth4      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:01:42:91  
          inet addr:10.132.63.191  Bcast:10.132.63.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1346288 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:438844 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:276243478 (263.4 MiB)  TX bytes:116188062 (110.8 MiB)
```

So here's the script I came up with.

```
/app/myPublicIp.sh 
defaultInterface=$(route | grep default | awk '{print $(NF)}')
ifconfig $defaultInterface | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 |  awk '{ print $1}'
```

Here's it executing:

```
/app/ipFor.sh 
10.132.63.191
```

Comment: Nice, +1. You could simplify (well, shorten it anyway) that to `ifconfig $(route | grep -oP '^default.*\s+\K.*') | grep -oP 'inet addr:\K[^\s]+')`

Comment: If you're going to do this on Linux, you might consider using procfs instead of parsing :-)

Comment: @ChrisDown... would that be via /proc/net? Yeah, this is for a Docker cluster.

Comment: @MarcellodeSales Yeah, `/proc/net/route`. I've posted an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite one is following.

Get the default interface:

```
$ ip r | grep -oP 'default .* \K.+'
eth0
```

Get the ip of an interface:

```
$ ip a show eth0 | grep -oP 'inet \K[\d\.]+'
10.33.44.135
```

Combined:

```
$ ip a show $(ip r | grep -oP 'default .* \K.+') | grep -oP 'inet \K[\d\.]+'
10.33.44.135
```

Comment: Unfortunately these fail on RHEL/CentOS 8 as the `ip r` output has changed slightly, with the metric being the last entry on the line and not the `dev ensNNN` or `dev ethN`.

Answer (score 1):

One other approach is:

```
ip a|awk /$(ip r|awk '/default/ { print $5 }')/|awk '/inet/ { print $2 }'| cut -f1 -d"/"
```

the benefit of this is that uses only `ip a` and `ip r` that is available by default at all linux systems

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is the IP address assigned to the default interface (which is what I understood from the comments under the question), using the Swiss army knife of network setup (`ip`) should be enough:

```
$ ip route | grep '^default'
default via 10.176.143.1 dev eth1  metric 203 
$ ip addr show eth1
4: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether c0:de:f1:72:30:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.176.143.71/24 brd 10.176.143.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This shortens to

```
$ ip addr show \
    $( /sbin/ip route \
        | grep '^default'\
        | sed 's/^.*dev \([^ \t]*\) .*$/\1/' )
```

which is ugly, because it is parsing something that probably wasn't really meant to be parsed (output of `ip route`), but should work.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Command with the default interface.**

```
ip -o route get "8.8.8.8" 2>/dev/null | sed -e 's/^.* src \([^ ]*\) .*$/\1/'
```

**or**

```
ip route | grep src | awk -F 'src' '{print $NF; exit}' | awk '{print $1}'
```

**or**

```
ip route | sed -n 's/.* src \(.*\) metric .*/\1/p' | uniq
```

**Tested on All Unix OS**

Comment: Unfortunately this fails on RHEL/CentOS 8 as the `ip r` output has changed slightly, with the metric being the last entry on the line and not the `dev ensNNN` or `dev ethN` so it prints the whole line instead of just the IP.

Comment: @dragon788 - Please read my updated answer. Hope this should work!!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Centos 7. Find default interface using `ip`

```
ifconfig $(ip route | awk '/default/ { print $5 }') | grep "inet " | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: the issue is that you need to have installed ifconfig

Answer (score 0):

Any Linux OS-es using `/proc` (but without using `iproute` tools):

```
cat /proc/net/fib_trie|grep -A50 '\|-- 0\.0\.0\.0$'|grep -B50 -wm1 'LOCAL'|tail -n2|grep -oP '\|-- \K\S+'
```

Answer (score 0):

To return the IP address of the default interface from a script, you can use the following commands:

```bash
IP=$(hostname -I)
echo $IP
```

or simply:

```bash
hostname -I
```

This works on Ubuntu and Raspberry Pi OS, but not on macOS.

Comment: Please note that this will display _all_ IP addresses on _all_ interfaces, not just the one with the default route to the internet.