# What's the shortest way to find my WAN IP address at the command line?

Tags: shell, command-line, ip

What's the shortest command I could use to find out my WAN IP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found:

```
$ curl ifconfig.me
73.4.164.110
```

So of course I made an alias

```
$ alias myip='curl ifconfig.me'
$
$ myip
73.4.164.110
```

Comment: [How can I get my external IP address](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22615) so `curl ifcfg.me` is even shorter.