# Is there a command line program to check IP location (for VPN)?

Tags: openvpn, vpn, debugging

There are a plethora of websites that will try to deduce your location from your IP address. For example: https://nordvpn.com/what-is-my-ip/.

This is handy for debugging VPNs - if I visit one of these sites and the location corresponds to the reported server location, rather than where I actually am, then I'm reasonably sure the VPN is working.

I'd like to be able to use a tool like this from the command line, where I can't operate a complicated web browser. Does such a tool exist?

For what it's worth, I am running Gentoo using [OpenVPN](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/OpenVPN), and my provider is [Private Internet Access](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/). But I hope that there's a reasonably cross-platform solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the external IP address in shell without dig in 2016?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254328/get-the-external-ip-address-in-shell-without-dig-in-2016)

Comment: @muru Doesn't seem so - they appear to only deal with IP addresses, but not location. I also get a different answer from the IP I'm sure of with the cloudflare solution suggested there (`dig @1.1.1.1 TXT whoami.cloudflare.com +short`), but I don't know why.

Comment: If you are required to host this yourself, this functionality can be achieved by a small script on a public webserver. [I have provided an example here.](https://lab.theresno.cloud/panki/remotekit/-/raw/master/ip.py)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [ipinfo.io](http://ipinfo.io) or [ipstack.com](http://ipstack.com) services through `curl`:
`curl --silent "https://ipinfo.io/ip"`
similarly change `ip` to `country` to get your geographical location.