# How do I know for sure proxychains is really working to mask my ip address by chaining it?

Tags: proxychains

I'm wondering if there is a way to know that proxychains is really working.

I know about configuring it, adding proxies, etc.. Just not really sure if it's actually working?

When I go into terminal and type proxychains (program name) it seems like it's working, but is there a way to know 100%?

Answer (score 1):

I believe checking your external IP by going through particular proxy is the way. Check this out [How can I get my external IP address in a shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/how-can-i-get-my-external-ip-address-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

open your web browser with proxcychain command

```
proxychains firefox
```

and then go to this webpage

https://www.dnsleaktest.com/

if it shows u different location, it means it is working. u can also click on test button and see more details.

make sure that your dns server also changed