# How does dig find my WAN-IP-address? What is "myip.opendns.com" doing?

Tags: dns, dig, dyndns

I needed to automatically get my own WAN-IP-address from my router. I found this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/how-can-i-get-my-external-ip-address-in-a-shell-script?newreg=dd6176b082c642f3ba5f14624cb661b4) and, among others, a solution with `dig` was proposed:

```
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

It works perfectly, but now I want to understand what it is doing.
Here is what I (hope to) understand so far (please correct me, if I am wrong):

- `+short` just gives me a short output
- `@resolver1.opendns.com` is the DNS server,
  which is asked what IP address belongs to the given domain

What's not clear to me is `myip.opendns.com`. If I would write `www.spiegel.de` instead, I would get the IP address of the domain [www.spiegel.de](http://www.spiegel.de), right?
With `myip.opendns.com` I get the WAN-IP of my router. So is `myip.opendns.com` just emulating a domain, which is resolved to my router?
How does it do it? Where does it get my IP from? And how is it different to what webpages, like e.g., [www.wieistmeineip.de](http://www.wieistmeineip.de), are doing? They also try to get my IP.

In the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/how-can-i-get-my-external-ip-address-in-a-shell-script?newreg=dd6176b082c642f3ba5f14624cb661b4) of Krinkle on the question I mentioned, it is stated
that this "dns-approach" would be better than the "http-approach". 
Why is it better and what is the difference?

There has to be a difference, because the WAN-IP I get from `dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com` (ip1) is the one I can also see in the web interface of my router, whereas `www.wieistmeineip.de` (and other similar sites too) is giving me another IP address (ip2).
I could imagine that my ISP is using some kind of sub-LAN, so that my requests to webservers are going through another (ISP-) router which has ip2, so that `www.wieistmeineip.de` is just seeing this address (ip2). But, again, what is `myip.opendns.com` doing then?

Additionally: Opening ip1 from within my LAN is giving me the test website from my RasPi, opening it from the outside of my LAN (mobile internet) does not work. Does it mean, that ip1 is no proper "internet IP" but more like a LAN IP?

Comment: The `myip.opendns.com` service stopped working for me recently. I switched to using the Google DNS option provided in @Mafketel's answer.

Comment: Same here, it just responds with opendns.com IPs.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First to summarize the general usage of [`dig`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dig): it requests the IP assigned to the given domain from the default DNS server. So e.g. `dig google.de` would request the IP assigned to the domain `google.de`. That would be `172.217.19.99`.

The command you mentioned is:

```
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

What this command does is: it sends a request for the IP of the domain `myip.opendns.com` to the DNS server `resolver1.opendns.com`. This server is programmed that, if this special domain is requested, the IP **the request comes from** is sent back.

The reasons why the method of querying the WAN IP using DNS is better were mentioned by krinkle: standardised, more stable and faster.

Note that per default, `dig` asks for the IPv4 address ([DNS `A` record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types)). If `dig` establishes a connection to opendns.com via IPv6, you'll get no result back (since you asked for your IPv4 address but have an IPv6 address in use). Thus, a more robust command might be:

```
dig +short ANY @resolver1.opendns.com myip.opendns.com
```

This will return your IP address, version 4 or 6, depending on `dig`'s connection. To specify an IP version, use `dig -4` or `dig -6` as shown in [Mafketel's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335371/how-does-dig-find-my-wan-ip-address-what-is-myip-opendns-com-doing#495954).

---

The reason I could imagine for those two IPs is that your router caches DNS requests and returns an old IP.

Another problem could be [DualStack Lite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_transition_mechanism#Dual-Stack_Lite_.28DS-Lite.29). That is often used by new internet contracts. Do you know whether your ISP is using DS Lite?

Comment: -So, if I understand your answer correctly, both methods are using the same mechanism (just looking at the ip, the request came from; but in case of "dns approach" in a more standardised way)?
-Whether my ISP uses DS Lite I don't know. How can i find out?
-Regarding your idea of my router caching old  ... stuff (ips, dns requests?): Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Actually I don't think, that's the case. I think, the correct ip is displayed by my router to me. This is also the one that the dig command gives me. But the guy of my ISP on the phone told me, that this ip should not be a "public" one, therefor my raspi is not reachable and these websites are giving me other ips.
But then it remains: How are dig and opendns.com getting my "internal" (intermediate-internal) ip?

Comment: Another option: `wget -O - -q icanhazip.com`

Answer (score 21):

Google provides the same service.

For [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4):

```
dig -4 TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com
```

For [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6):

```
dig -6 TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com
```

where `TXT` is a [DNS record type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TXT_record).

Comment: welcome to U&L, note that accepted answer may or may not work, in my case it didn't work from home (at least from one of my ISP), but ir work from some host at work (2 tested out of many).

Comment: `myip.opendns.com` still works for me, *but* I do have to specify the `-4` flag if my WAN connection also has a IPv6 IP address. Otherwise it prints nothing.

Comment: For ipv6 via opendns: `dig +short -6 myip.opendns.com aaaa @resolver1.ipv6-sandbox.opendns.com`

Comment: You can pipe those commands into **sed** to remove the closing quotes. ```dig -4 TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com | sed 's|"||g'``` ```dig -6 TXT +short o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns1.google.com | sed 's|"||g'```

Comment: Interestingly, this only works when using `ns*.google.com`. When using `8.8.8.8` or `8.8.4.4`, bogus values are returned. Not sure why that is, though.