# How to get SOHO server IP address to laptop?

Tags: scripting

Pursuant to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/how-can-i-get-my-external-ip-address-in-a-shell-script:), what are some good ways to get that information to an external host? Can I encrypt it first? I've sent it in the clear before  with email but I've also gotten my mail blocked before by overzealous SPAM filters.

Comment: https://freedns.afraid.org/ will net you add it to there dns. Thus allowing a DNS lookup. (not encrypted, but if you are relying on you IP address being secret, for security, then you have no security at all.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is *really* broad, but there are several ways you could put the data into a fetchable location:

Have another host with a static IP?  `scp` your IP to a text file stored thereupon in a `cron` job.  You could even put this in a place served by Apache.  If you don't want your IP to be knowable, you can put that file behind a Basic HTTP Auth filter to keep the unwashed masses out.

Use a service like NoIP or dyndns.org, and set up the relevant service on your host to keep the name record current.

Use a commandline tool to SMS the IP to your phone.

Set up Dropbox or Bt-Sync, drop your IP in there; read that file from other hosts set up with the synced directory.

This is a cat with *many many* skins.

Comment: I know it's broad but it's an issue many have. ...isn't there a means by which you can use a chat system? I'd like to avoid any unnecessary fees and hopefully make it as automated as possible. Like maybe I could use a script to update an entry in my /etc/hosts file or my ~/.ssh/config I'ld like a system where the change is detected and the message is sent periodically until the laptop responds with "Oh, yeah, I got that message and have updated my files."

Comment: Like I said, options are myriad.  You could give your server its own Twitter account which it tweets its IPs to.  Set it to private so only you can see it's tweets.  You could use any number of command line tools to send it to IRC, AIM, YIM, Jabber, or wherever you like.

Comment: Is it possible using some kind of secured peer to peer net? That would be ideal but I've never heard of anything like that. Doh! I could use an encrypted torrent!

Comment: The aforementioned BT-Sync is _exactly_ that.  And is free for personal use.

Comment: In the end I just got dynamic dns. It was cheap anyway. If I ask someone who doesn't do Linux to use something they normally wouldn't... ;-)  It will be hard enough just to convince them to use WinSCP.