# Why doesn't dig myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com use sshuttle's proxy?

Tags: ip, vpn, proxy, ssh-tunneling, dig

I am using the great technique from [How can I get my external IP address in a shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/how-can-i-get-my-external-ip-address-in-a-shell-script) to find my public IP address:

```
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

I'm also using sshuttle as a proxy over ssh tunnel. It is started to forward traffic on all ports and IPs (including DNS requests) using the following command:

```
sshuttle --dns -vr usr@sshserver 0/0
```

After the proxy has started I visit https://canihazip.com/s to verify that my external IP has changed. It has, but when I run the dig command again, it reports the same external IP reported as before the proxy was started.

From the verbose output, sshuttle seems to be forwarding on other dig commands, and checking https://dnsleaktest.com only reveals the IP on the other end on my proxy, as expected. As far as I can tell sshuttle seems to be working.

Can anyone explain why the dig command reports my external IP before the proxy? My aim is make it seem to the opendns servers that the request is originating from my ssh server.

It's a bit over my head, but I had a quick look in Wireshark and when filtering for DNS traffic Wireshark doesn't see any DNS requests apart from the above DIG command. The command is bypassing the proxy.

I'm happy to use any of the other (less elegant) ways to find my external IP, but this makes me ask the question: what else is bypassing sshuttle?

Comment: Would you able to explain this better, or provide evidences? It sounds strange the same command producing different results.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I'd added some clarity, does that help? The command is run _before_ the proxy, then _after_, but both give me the same external IP. Despite [icanhazip](https://canihazip.com/s) giving me different external IPs. Any specific evidence you are looking for?

Comment: That explains it, it was not entirely clear the first command was done without using the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have used the `-v` option to show debug message when running shuttle command, you can find that shuttle created some iptables rules. One of the rules is as follows:

```
iptables -t nat -A sshuttle-12300 -j REDIRECT --dest <nameserver>/32 -p udp --dport 53 --to-ports 12299
```

The rule above redirects the DNS request sent to `<nameserver>` to shuttle proxy port. Shuttle finds these `<nameserver>`s in `/etc/resolv.conf` file and automatically create iptables rules accroding to them.

So when the dig command make DNS queries using the nameserver defined in `/etc/resolv.conf` file, it will be proxied by sshuttle, but if not, it will not be proxied.

In your case, the address of `resolver1.opendns.com` which is `208.67.222.222` is not defined in your `/etc/resolv.conf`, so it will not be proxied by sshuttle.

Answer (score 0):

The gateway has two external IP addresses. The NAT running on the gateway employs some kind of load balancing. It can be based on the destination IP or protocol type. If this is the case the source IP address of the DNS queries and HTTP packets will be different.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. What gateway? How is dig leaking my "true"  (un-tunnelled) IP?

Comment: My bad, please ignore the response