# how do i check if an input argument of a bash script is a base ten number?

Tags: linux, shell-script

I need to check if the input argument of a bash script is a base ten number. How can I do?

Comment: Possibly related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/482822/bash-script-make-for-work and to its duplicate (homework questions from the last few days/weeks).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get my external IP address in a shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/how-can-i-get-my-external-ip-address-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: Is 5.0 a base 10 number? Or 4.2e2?

Answer (score 1):

Your can use pattern matching (improve on the regex if you don't want to accept a leading 0):

```
if [[ $num =~ ^[+-]?[1-9][0-9]*$ ]]
then
echo Decimal
else
echo Not decimal
fi
```

Comment: Yes to both, edited.

Answer (score 0):

Compare it to itself while forcing base-ten interpretation.
As seen in the shell Arithmetic manual:

> Constants with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal numbers. A leading
>   ‘0x’ or ‘0X’ denotes hexadecimal. Otherwise, numbers take the form
>   ***[base#]n***, where the optional base is a decimal number between 2 and 64
>   representing the arithmetic base, and n is a number in that base. If
>   base# is omitted, then base 10 is used. When specifying n, the digits
>   greater than 9 are represented by the lowercase letters, the uppercase
>   letters, ‘@’, and ‘_’, in that order. If base is less than or equal to
>   36, lowercase and uppercase letters may be used interchangeably to
>   represent numbers between 10 and 35.

Therefore if it's the first argument you can do...

***EDITED AGAIN TO ACCOMMODATE NEGATIVE INPUT***

```
#!/bin/bash
b=${1#-}
if [[ $b =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then                       #If it's all numbers
        a=$((10#$b))                                #create a base 10 version
        if [ "$a" == "$b" ]; then                   #if they LOOK the same...
                echo "$b is Base 10!"; exit 1; fi;  #It's base 10; exit.
fi
    echo "$b is not base 10"                        #If it has letters or $a and $b look different, it's not base 10.
```

This code will take any input and tell you if it is base 10 or not. The arg is stripped of a negative sign first, then compared with $a non-numerically, because 012 -eq $((10#012)); but we don't want the script to tell us it's base ten because it isn't.

```
root@xxxx:~# ./testing.sh -124124
124124 is Base 10!
root@xxxx:~# ./testing.sh 58135
58135 is Base 10!
root@xxxx:~# ./testing.sh aksjflkfj929148
aksjflkfj929148 is not Base 10
```

Comment: Doesn't work, non numeric args elicit a `value too great for base`

Comment: @xenoid Edited :) Now takes all inputs!

Comment: @KuboLD Glad you liked my solution... But IMHO the adequate regexp is sufficient.

Comment: @xenoid Agreed. I just like the chance to take something and run with it whenever I can. This was fun!