# Print out IP address script

Tags: linux, centos, grep, scripting, wget

I need to make a script that gets my public IP address from a website and prints it out.

```
#!/bin/bash
wget http://www.ipchicken.com/

grep
```

I don't know where to go from here.

Please help

Comment: What do you mean by "get my ip address from a website and print it out"? Do you just want the ip address of the site itself?

Comment: what is your question? ... we should not have to guess what you want to know

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get my external IP address in a shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/how-can-i-get-my-external-ip-address-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
wget -qO- https://api.ipify.org; echo
```

See the API usage on [ipify.org](https://www.ipify.org/).

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is fragile; it depends on the format of the HTML document returned by ipchicken, and that can change without warning.  This currently works for me, your mileage may vary:

```
$ wget http://www.ipchicken.com/ -qO - | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b"
108.27.105.76
```

Comment: See @freddy 's answer; that doesn't depend on parsing the HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can use `http://plain-text-ip.com/`:

```
 wget -qO- http://plain-text-ip.com/; echo
 18?.1?.2?.5?
```